# Can a 8086 processor Label include more than one operation?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors

Label op ; this is a label for a one operation
Label :
op1
op2
Does this mean that op1 & op2 are in one Label?

Comment: a label is only a place, a single address.

Comment: depends on the assembler. gnu assembler I think you can.

Comment: Nothing is "in" a label.

Comment: A label is a marker for you to tell the assembler "there, the memory address where *this* instruction/data element ends up". Think about it: Can you describe what would it mean for "two opcodes to be on the same label"?

Answer (score 1):

A label does not "include" anything, it's an alias for an address

while writing assembler code, you often don't know, what the address of your code will be, so you add a label, to give the wanted address a "name"

e.g.:

```
org 0100h 

mov cx,100
back:                   ; tell the assembler to remember this address
    mov ah,9
    mov dl,'*'
    call myFunction     ; I have no idea where myFunction will be,
                        ; but the assembler will insert the correct address here
    ...
loop back               ; jump back to the address saved as label "back"
...
; more stuff
....
myFunction:              ; this address will be called
```

if you later add some code inbetween the call of "myFunction" and myFunction, the address where myFunction is will be changed, but you won't have to change the call

Comment: `myFunction` could be defined in another file, with just an `extern myFunction` assembler directive in the first source file.  Then it's the linker that sorts it out.

Comment: yes, you're totally right. I thought about mentioning external labels, but I wasn't sure the OP is famliar with assembling/linking, so it probably would have confused him more than it'd helped